# Не работает css в JavaFX!

Tags: javafx, java, css

На одной сцене работает, а на другой, на которую я навесил обработчик, нет.
Сделал даже по гайду от одного разработчика: http://ru.intechcore.com/javafx-and-css-styles/ - не помогло. css находится там же, где и картинки и весь остальной код, - всё в одном пакете **/src/sample**. Единственная разница в том, что там, где работает CSS, я не использовал подгрузку через FXMLLoader, а во втором случае - использовал. : )

Код использую следующий:

```
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Parent root = null;
        try {
            root = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/buttonGrid.fxml"));
            root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/sample/Board.css").toExternalForm());
            currentStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            currentStage.setResizable(false);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

В этом же классе расположен тот же вызов `getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("file.css").toExternalForm());`, только файл css другой и вызов `getStylesheets()` применен к другому объекту Scene, но к одному и тому же объекту Stage.

В чем проблема?

**Обновление**

Странно... поребилдил/пособирал проект, побегал по опциям в Compiler...
Пропала ошибка Error Loading Image, которая недавно возникала. А также новая ошибка тоже пропала - javafx module not specified (непонятно почему). Видимо, с первой ошибкой и было связано то, что css файл мой не обрабатывался совсем. ( Очень, очень странно.

Кажется, понял. Что-то случилось с кешем проекта, потому что любые изменения в .fxml файле он не фиксирует после запуска...

P.S.: Переустановил IDE, пересоздал проект. Проблема та же.

Видимо, придется похоронить мне эту тему (

Comment: Всё там работает... руки кривые. Error Loading Image - так и не выяснил его природу, а тут опять-таки нужен был setLocation() ))))